# Google Web Toolkit - FlexTable

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

In Flextable, every table cell just only can add 1 widget only?
If I want to add more widgets, can I add panel inside the cell then add all the widget inside the panel?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a panel (FlowPanel or HTMLPanel, for example) inside a cell, and then add as many widgets to it as you need.